# Fast way to search in pre-known map with limited space in C

Tags: c

I have the following mapping:

```
{
    0x00: 0U,
    0x10: 1U, 
    0x11: 1U,
    0x20: 0U,
    0x25: 1U,
    0x40: 0U,
    .... so on
}
```

The max key value is around 200, but the number of keys is actually around 30.

I have to find the value (0U or 1U) for a particular key (for e.g. 0x11 in the above case) out of around 30 keys.

What would be the fast ways to achieve this in C? Note that the approach cannot go too heavy on code/data space also. Also, would some approaches be better for much larger maps?

Some possible ways came to my mind:

1. Create an array of the keys having value as 0U or 1U, whichever has lesser numbers and find in there using linear/binary search.
2. Use switch case as follows:

```
val = 1U;
switch(input)
{
    case 0x00:
    case 0x20:
    case 0x40:
        val = 0U;
        break;
}
```

3. Creating a map of size max(key), with each index having either 0 or 1. To find value for a key, just de-reference the array with the offset.
   The problem I see here is that the max(key) can be quite large for my case (200), although actual number of keys is not much (around 30).
4. Create a map using two arrays/array of structs. This would require find operation, so I think would be similar to approach 1.

I am not sure how these approaches would exactly compare with each other, especially approach 2.

Comment: This is unanswerable.  You've not provided the exact mapping and then made the conflicting requirements "fast but small" which any answer must depend on.

Comment: Try them all to see which is "best".

Comment: Try out the various approaches for your actual input, time them, and select the fastest.

Comment: as soon as values are only 0 or 1, I'd say bitset, it is part of standard c++ library, not sure about c though, but it is very easy to implement and you will spend only 26 bytes

Comment: *"What would be the fast ways to achieve this in C? Note that the approach cannot go too heavy on code/data space also.*" You must decide which you want to prioritise. 201 bytes for a look-up byte array, or 26 butes for a look-up bit array with more computation. *"Also, would some approaches be better for much larger maps?*" A sorted `struct` array and binary search.

Comment: What's the context in which 200 bytes is considered "a lot"?

Comment: You might be able to find patterns in your keys using a Karnough map: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map

Comment: For lookups of data known at (before) compile time, consider [perfect hashing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_hash_function).

Comment: If you do the `switch case`, you may find that your compiler turns it into some kind of lookup table/tree on its own. But you would have to examine the resulting assembly to check the details.

Comment: Do you need to map unknown key values to a value other than 0U or 1U?

Comment: What exactly does "cannot go too heavy on code/data space" mean?  For example, is one byte per possible distinct key (so around 200 bytes) too large for the representation of the map?  That would be a convenient size, but smaller is possible.

Comment: For a faster lookup you only need to search for keys  with *one* of those values. If the key isn't found, it must be the other value. So search for the set with the fewer keys.

Comment: Do you need to be able to recognize unmapped keys?

Answer (score 3):

Encode the table as a string of bytes (25 bytes for 200 bits) and look up an element with `(uint8_t) S[key/8] >> key%8 & 1`.

Comment: Please note that if max key is 200 you need actually need 26 bytes, with last byte having 7 bits unused.

Comment: This probably won't make a least bit difference to most people, but since question asked about fast way: It might be slightly faster to use native register size type for array; for example, `uint32_t` instead of `uint8_t` on 32-bit processor, to avoid need for zero extension. Whether or not this actually has observable effect depends on use case.

Answer (score 0):

Simply make a look-up table.

```c
#define MAX_SIZE 200

const uint8_t LOOKUP [MAX_SIZE] = 
{
  [0x10] = 1U, 
  [0x11] = 1U,
  [0x25] = 1U,
};

...

uint8_t val = LOOKUP[input];
```

This is very fast and *small* - small enough to fit the flash resonably well even the tiniest, crappiest 8-bit MCUs still in production. 200 bytes is nothing.

If you for reasons unknown insists on using a MCU which is even crappier than the crappiest and therefore can't even afford 200 bytes of flash, then you just have to deal with slower look-up:

```c
const uint8_t LOOKUP [] = 
{
  0x10, 0x11, 0x25,
};

uint8_t val = 0U;
for(uint8_t i=0; i<sizeof(LOOKUP)/sizeof(*LOOKUP); i++)
{
  if(LOOKUP[i] == input)
  {
    val = 1U;
    break;
  }
}
```

On such archaic CPUs, division can often be slower than looping through all 30 bytes using a dumb linear search like above, so be careful before deciding to use the `/` or `%`operators. Binary search might not improve things either, with such a small amount of data. Pick whatever algorithm that suits the dinosaur MCU best - you don't mention which one you are using.